# Parallel tasks in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Suppose I have a few tasks to run in parallel in Java. Each task returns either success or failure. Each task has an associated deadline. If a task does not finish by the deadline it is interrupted (all tasks are *interruptable*) and returns failure.

If one of the tasks fails (i.e. return failure) we interrupt all other tasks, which are still running.

We should wait till *all* tasks finish and finally return either success if all tasks return success or failure if at least one task returns failure.

How would you implement it? I am going to use *util.concurrent*. Which library primitives would you suggest?

Comment: This sounds quite similar to `ExecutorService.invokeAll`, except that that has a single timeout for all the tasks rather than independent timeouts for each sub-task.

Comment: @IanRoberts I am afraid I really need independent timeouts for each task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecutorCompletionService seems closest

```
    ExecutorService ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    ExecutorCompletionService<Boolean> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<Boolean>(
            ex);
    List<Callable<Boolean>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Boolean>>();
       ... add tasks
    List<Future<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Boolean>>();
    for (Callable<Boolean> t : tasks) {
        futures.add(cs.submit(t));
    }
    for (!futures.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            Future<Boolean> f = cs.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            futures.remove(f);  // poll returns the same instance of Future as in the futures list
            if (f == null || !f.get()) {  // poll returns null on timeout
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // cancel remaining tasks, if all finished OK the list will be empty
    for (Future<Boolean> future : futures) {
        future.cancel(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ExecutorService` with `CountDownLatch` and a array list of `Future` interface to hold the tasks:

```
List<List<String>> elements = MyPartition.partition(bigObjectList, size); 
List<Future<?>> tasks = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
CountDownLatch doneSignal =  new CountDownLatch(10);
for(List<String> l: elements) {         
   ReadTask worker = new ReadTask(doneSignal, l);
   tasks.add(executor.submit(worker));
}   

long timeout = 10000;
doneSignal.await(timeout, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
boolean notFinished = false;
if(doneSignal.getCount() > 0) {
  for(Future<?> fut : tasks) {
    if(!fut.isDone()) {
      System.out.println("Sub Thread " + fut + " has not finshed!");
      fut.cancel(true);             
      notFinished = true;
    }
  }
}
```